# Interface overloading

Tags: c#, java, android, interface

I have created an `interface Response`

```
Interface Response{
   public output(String s);
}
```

and i implement this interface on my `class A` . now i have a `class B` too and it also need to implement this interface but it need different parameter for interface method. (mean class B needs `public output(Comment c);`)

So my question is , do i need to create another interface for class B because it need different parameter

Like this

```
 Interface Response{
   public output(Comment c);
}
```

or is there any way to handle this.
also can i used `object data type` for this.?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you interacting with the class `B` through its interfaces or through its own methods?

Comment: Did you intend to tag this as both C# and Java?

Comment: i think this is common for both C# and java.

Comment: basically i am trying to do this .(the 1st answer on this page). He create interface for only String data type but i also need this interface for other datatypes as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: Maybe, but many of the people who come here will be expert in EITHER Java OR C#, and not know whether their answer applies to both.  So in its current form, this question should only be answered by people who know both languages.  Also, someone might want to include a code snippet in their answer - what are they to do?  You should specify which language you actually care about, whether you believe the answer is "common to both" or not.

Comment: i removed the C# tag.

Comment: I suspect what you actually want is a generic.  I could explain to you how they work in Java, but I don't know how C# generics work.

Comment: explain for java please and thanks for your kind help.

Comment: basically i need this in my android code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note, this answer applies to Java.  I am not a C# expert.**

I believe you want

```
public interface Response<T> {
    void output(T arg);
}
```

Then you can write

```
public class ClassA implements Response<String> {
    public void output(String arg) {
       // etc
```

and also

```
public class ClassB implements Response<Comment>
    public void output(Comment arg) {
       // etc
```

Comment: i will try this and then let you know. thanks any way.

Comment: if i used object data type.should it make any difference.?

Comment: The interface here doesn't put any restrictions on `T`, so it can be any type you like.

Comment: no. i meant to say if i dont use generic and instead of this just use object data type like void output(Object o); so then it make any difference.i can cast object to my custom class ass well as for string.

Comment: It will work, but I don't recommend it.  Throwing away the type safety that generics give you will make things more difficult when you come to maintain this code in the future.